# google Material Icons are not rendering properly on any website in chrome browser on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, google-fonts, google-material-icons

There must be a problem with internal Ubuntu's font conflict or some bugs. Unable to find the what is the reason for this. Please, share any solution.

Using Ubuntu 20.04, with Google Chrome: Version 104.0.5112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the leading cause for the problem in my case. I was using an addon for the font-pack, "Hindi Font Pack". I disabled it, and the problem solved itself.

[image]